# independent events (probability)

Tags: probability

Two people $A$ and $B$, one by one draw one ball each from a purse containing $5$ white and one red ball and then keep it aside, the person who gets the red ball wins the game, find the probability if $A$ wins?

[image]

Comment: Please use Mathjax to render the math thank you.

Comment: I am new here XD, I don't know what u mean by Mathjax and also I dont know how to post a question using that? :/

Comment: Pls refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Alright guys, will do , thank you XD

Comment: Wait, do they continue drawing balls until someone wins?

Comment: they continue untill a person gets a red ball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may seem counter intuitive, but the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$. It's not hard to see with a little case work
$$P(A)=\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6}·\frac{4}{5}·\frac{1}{4}+\frac{5}{6}·\frac{4}{5}·\frac{3}{4}·\frac{2}{3}·\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

But I want you to think of this: let's say $A$ and $B$ play a different game, one in which they split the six balls three each. In this new game, obviously, the chance of $A$ winning is $\frac{1}{2}$, **again**. This is not a coincidence, these two games are pretty much the same.

In the original game, let's say the players continued to draw balls even after one of them got the red ball. Then at the end they are each left with 3 balls, and it basically becomes equivalent to the two players playing the second game.